# Unit testing in angular 6 with ngx-logger dependency

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

Is there a way to properly test classes that have `ngx-logger` as dependency in angular (Assuming we may be using some known framework for testing, like jasmine)? So far there isn't a resource that can help me to provide a use case where the `ngx-logger` was mocked or provided in unit tests for classes that have this dependency.

Comment: If you add the code for the component and the complete .spec file you've attempted, then StaclkOverflow users could help you more fully.  StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to illustrate the specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Just wanted an example or a resource that could help me with creating tests for this dependency. Just stumbled upon [this](https://github.com/dbfannin/ngx-logger/blob/master/src/lib/logger.service.spec.ts) resource that helped me. Thanks for pointing it out though. How do I close this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I found the solution [here](https://github.com/dbfannin/ngx-logger/blob/master/src/lib/logger.service.spec.ts) for anyone who may be facing this problem.

Answer (score 4):

As explained in [NGXLogger docs](https://github.com/dbfannin/ngx-logger#testing-your-app-when-using-ngxlogger), import `LoggerTestingModule` in your tests:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    LoggerTestingModule
  ],
  ...
});
```